# Dropping Columns by name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

So I have a data-frame structured as:

```
> head(peakQ)
  STATION_NUMBER DATA_TYPE YEAR PEAK_CODE PRECISION_CODE MONTH DAY HOUR MINUTE TIME_ZONE  PEAK SYMBOL
1        05EE006         Q 1983         H             NA     6  29    5     18       MST 1.980       
2        05EE006         Q 1985         H             NA     4   2    0      0       MST 1.380      B
3        05EE006         Q 1986         H             NA     3  30   13     37       MST 2.640       
4        05EE006         Q 1987         H             NA     4   5   21      2       MST 1.590      B
5        05EE006         Q 1989         H             NA    10  22    2     45       MST 0.473       
6        05EE006         Q 1990         H             NA     4   2    4      2       MST 1.470
```

I want to drop the columns; STATION_NUMBER, DATA_TYPE, PEAK_CODE, PRECISION_CODE

But, **I want to assume that I know only the column names and not their index.**

I already know that it is trivial to use indexes, such as:

```
> head(peakQ[, -c(1, 2, 4, 5)])
  YEAR MONTH DAY HOUR MINUTE TIME_ZONE  PEAK SYMBOL
1 1983     6  29    5     18       MST 1.980       
2 1985     4   2    0      0       MST 1.380      B
3 1986     3  30   13     37       MST 2.640       
4 1987     4   5   21      2       MST 1.590      B
5 1989    10  22    2     45       MST 0.473       
6 1990     4   2    4      2       MST 1.470
```

but, **why do I get an error using column names? and, what is the workaround?**

```
> head(peakQ[, -c("STATION_NUMBER", "DATA_TYPE", "PEAK_CODE", "PRECISION_CODE")])
Error in -c("STATION_NUMBER", "DATA_TYPE", "PEAK_CODE", "PRECISION_CODE") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
```

I am especially confused because the opposite operation works just fine.

```
> head(peakQ[, c("STATION_NUMBER", "DATA_TYPE", "PEAK_CODE", "PRECISION_CODE")])
  STATION_NUMBER DATA_TYPE PEAK_CODE PRECISION_CODE
1        05EE006         Q         H             NA
2        05EE006         Q         H             NA
3        05EE006         Q         H             NA
4        05EE006         Q         H             NA
5        05EE006         Q         H             NA
6        05EE006         Q         H             NA
```

Any help and/or a deeper explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no minus operator on character vectors; however, `subset` tries to simulate this using a vector of unevaluated names.  Ditto for dplyr `select`.  We could also use `setdiff` which avoids the need for a minus operator.

**1) subset** Try `subset` with the `select=` argument:

```
subset(peakQ, select = - c(STATION_NUMBER, DATA_TYPE, PEAK_CODE, PRECISION_CODE))
```

**2) setdiff** Another possibility is:

```
peakQ[setdiff(names(peakQ), c("STATION_NUMBER","DATA_TYPE","PEAK_CODE","PRECISION_CODE"))]
```

**3) dplyr** The dplyr package's `select` could also be used:

```
library(dplyr)
peakQ %>%
      select(- c(STATION_NUMBER, DATA_TYPE, PEAK_CODE, PRECISION_CODE))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "exclude" operator only works with indices and not column names. A remedy to overcome this problem might be to subset the column names with the %in% and ! operators:

```
> cols <- letters[1:5]
> cols
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> df1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, rep(list(1:5), 5)))
> names(df1) <- cols
> df1
  a b c d e
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5
> df1[,-c("a","b")]
Error in -c("a", "b") : invalid argument to unary operator
> df1[,!names(df1) %in% c("a","b")]
  c d e
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
```

Comment: pls look for similar qsns before answering.

Comment: Let us say Data is your data set and your ColumnName is col then below is the command.                                                                 
                                                                                                 
Example  Data<- subset(Data, select = - c(col))